# AngularJS ng-src does not load new image with same url

Tags: angularjs

Currently I'm showing an image with the following code:

```
<img ng-src="{{user.profileImage}}") class='img-circle photo' />
```

The user is able to change that photo using an upload function. The profileImage will be overwritten because filename is renamed to the users _id. So for example the path is: `https://some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/5cfa5fb5850b2755d89574cc.png`.

After a successful upload the path stays the same, but the content on the url will become different, the image will still show the old image, even after reloading the whole `$scope.user`.

I tried to use an different path for the image like `data.profileImage` and clearing `user.profileImage` before loading, adding `ng-if="user.profileImage !=''` to the image, but it isn't working.

Is there a way to reload the image without reloading the whole page?

I didn't paste the upload code, I think it's not necessary for this issue.

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue. Try appending `?<timestamp>` to user.profileImage

Comment: @user2954463 ow yeah. Please post that as an answer, so I can mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a browser caching issue, not ng-src problem.

Try appending `?<timestamp>` to value of user.profileImage.

This will force browser to fetch the new image.